# Angular 2 imagem base64 como usar?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-5

Estou com um erro de "ERR_INVALID_URL" e não carrega a imagem.
Alguém sabe como resolver ? o Meu html e o Ts estão assim.

```
//Aqui está vindo a url do servidor 
    let a = value.params["dataBuffer"]; 

    //Aqui estou convertendo o base64 passando para 
      variavel imagePath q é do tipo any;
    this.imagemPath = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("data:image/png;base64, a");



   ----- No meu arquivo HTML -----------
    <img [src]="imagemPath">
```

Comment: Qual url está sendo passada?

Comment: @HerbertJunior Estou usando o site https://www.base64-image.de/ ..Ele gera uma url enorme do tipo: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAACDQAAAFwCAYAAABNBblg.....

Comment: E quando voce cola na navegador, consegue ver a imagem normalmente?

Comment: Sim, consigo ver a imagem no navegador de boa.

Comment: @HerbertJunior No console mostra esse erro data:image/png;base64, a:1 GET data:image/png;base64, a net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Comment: Não deveria ser: `this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:image/png;base64, ' + a);`? No seu código voce está tentando usar a string a como base64.

Comment: @HerbertJunior Testei desse jeito q vc fez aqui, agora a url chega até o "a" mas da o mesmo erro de ERR_INVALID_URL . Continua não trazendo a imagem. :(

Comment: Tente utilizar esse tutorial http://www.manuelmeyer.net/2014/12/tooltip-decoding-base64-images-with-chrome-data-url/

Comment: Qual a utilidade desse?  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de usar o recurso `sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` você pode colocar o código base64 direto no atributo `src`:

```
this.imagemPath = `data:image/png;base64, ${a}`;
```

**Verifique se durante a sua conversão para base64 a string de retorno já vem com o trecho '`data:image/png;base64,` ', se vier não será necessário a concatenação acima**